# ThreadPoolExecutor with all params from two lists

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x

I have two lists:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
b = [9, 8, 7, 6]
```

I'd like to have every combination of these two lists passed as argument to a function I'm multithreading:

```
def test(hello, world):
    return hello + world

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
    future_to_stuff = { executor.submit(self._http_check_port, hello, world): ### }
    for future in as_completed(future_to_port):
        ...
```

I'm trying to figure out how to "unpack" both my lists so that every combination of values in `a` and `b` are sent as params to the function.

Comment: I'm confused, what do you mean by "every combination of values in a and b"? Would it be a list with combinatory pairs? `[ (1, 9), (1, 8), (1, 7), (1, 6), (2, 9), (2, 8) ... etc]` ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I usually use following list comprehension.

```
future_to_stuff = [executor.submit(test, hello, world) 
                   for hello, world in zip(a, b)]
```

Here is a modified code.

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed

def test(hello, world):
    return hello + world

def main(a, b):
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
        future_to_stuff = [executor.submit(test, hello, world) 
                           for hello, world in zip(a, b)]
        for future in as_completed(future_to_stuff):
            print(future.result())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    b = [9, 8, 7, 6]
    main(a, b)
```

---

Another way is to use `.map` method instead of `.submit`.

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed

def test(hello, world):
    return hello + world

def main(a, b):
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
        results = executor.map(test, a, b)
        for result in results:
            print(result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    b = [9, 8, 7, 6]
    main(a, b)
```

Comment: When I run your examples I get `4` threads running, shouldn't there be 16 since we have two lists of 4 args? `(1,9) (1,8) (1,7) (1,6) (2,9) ... (4,6)`. Perhaps I didn't express my question clearly, but it doesn't seem like the `zip` or `map` are giving all possible values.

Comment: For that case, I think that all you need is to change the `zip`  to `permutation ` in itratortools module.